How to change CSS property inside a descendant selector
How do I change or remove style "width" property for img?


.main_box_img img {
  width: 100%;
}
<div class="main_box_img">
  <img src="...">
</div>



document.getElementsByClassName("main_box_img")[0].getElementsByTagName('img')[0].style is empty.
I can get width value using getComputedStyle(), but it's read-only.
Seems to be a simple question but I've found nothing.

what you are trying to do at the moment is change the inline style which is an option then i would end up looking like <img src="..." stlye = "width: 0px;">  but i believ you want to alter the stylesheet i dont remember exactly how its done but you need to select the stylesheet instead of the element

If the change is for a specific element, then changing the .style property is likely the way to go - read via getComputedStyle() then set via .style.  Alternatively, add a class to the element with predefined CSS (depending on what's needed).  Finally, you can update the style sheet directly by dynamically adding a <style> element.

That document.etc is empty because it only reads inline styles. But it does still allow to add an inline style: document.getElementsByClassName("main_box_img")[0].getElementsByTagName('img')[0].style.width = 'auto'.

if you need to remove a style from an element you could just use a specific modifier class for this purpose and then remove it via JavaScript.
e.g.


const mainboximg = document.querySelector('.mainbox');
mainboximg.classList.remove('mainbox--fullwidth');
.mainbox--fullwidth img {
  width: 100%
}
<div class="mainbox mainbox--fullwidth">
    <img src="...">
</div>



By removing that class the style will no longer affect the element.

Creating a css class for images within .main_box_img with width: 100% will enable removing the class later on. Furthermore: with querySelector[All] you can improve selecting elements (with elaborate css query selectors)


const images = document.querySelectorAll(`.main_box_img img`);

// modify
setTimeout(_ => images.forEach(image => 
  image.classList.remove(`max`, `min`)), 1500);
.main_box_img img.max {
  width: 25%;
}

.main_box_img img.min {
  width: 50px;
}
<div class="main_box_img">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100?random=1">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100?random=3" class="min">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100?random=2" class="max">
</div>




You can either:

Add a new class that override the previous style



const mainboxImg = document.querySelector('.mainbox img');

mainboxImg.classList.add('width-auto');
.mainbox--fullwidth img {
  width: 100%
}

.mainbox--fullwidth img.width-auto {
  width: auto;
}
<div class="mainbox mainbox--fullwidth">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200">
</div>




or remove the old class from the element



const mainboxImg = document.querySelector('.mainbox img');
mainboxImg.classList.remove('mainbox--fullwidth');
.mainbox--fullwidth img {
  width: 100%
}

.mainbox--fullwidth img.width-auto {
  width: auto;
}
<div class="mainbox mainbox--fullwidth">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200">
</div>




to alter the style sheet you can use the following code which is just a simple example:


<style id="uniqueStylesheet">
  .first-element {
    background-color: blue;
  }
  .second-element {
    background-color: blue;
  }
  .third-element {
    background-color: blue;
  }
  div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
  }
 </style>

<div class="first-element"></div>
<div class="second-element"></div>
<div class="third-element"></div>
<button onclick="modifyCSSRule()">Click me!!</button>

<script>
  function modifyCSSRule() {
    // Get stylesheets in the document
    let styleElement = document.getElementById('uniqueStylesheet');
  
    let sheet = styleElement.sheet || styleElement.styleSheet;

    let rules = sheet.cssRules || sheet.rules;

    for (let rule of rules) {
      if (rule.selectorText == '.second-element') {
        rule.style.setProperty('background-color', 'red', 'important');
      }
    }
  }
</script>



in this example you always know the second css rule in your stylesheet is the one that needs to be changed this way of coding is not preffered but it is the way you wanted it i believe
